# Get all employee who directly or indirectly reports to an employee, with hierarchy level no

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, iteration, primary-key

I have a Employee table like

```
emp_id bigint,
reports_to bigint,
emp_name varchar(20),
Constraint [PK_Emp] Primary key (emp_id),
Constraint [FK_Emp] Foreign key (reports_to) references [MSS].[dbo].[Emp]([emp_id])

emp_id         reports_to        emp_name
------         ------       --------------
1              null         Sumanta
2              1            Arpita
3              null         Pradip
4              1            Sujon
5              2            Arpan
6              5            Jayanti
```

I want to get all the employees that directly or indirectly reports to Sumanta or emp_id(1), and with hierarchy level, like this:

```
emp_id         hierarchy_level         emp_name
------         ---------------        ----------
2                    1                  Arpita
4                    1                  Sujon
5                    2                  Arpan
6                    3                 Jayanti
```

I am new to SQL and just couldn't find what to use or how to get those results. Is it worth a stored procedure with table valued variable, or just a Tsql select query will be enough. Any help is most welcome.

All I have done is-

```
Select Ep.emp_id,ep.emp_eame 
From Emp as E 
Inner Join Emp as Ep on Ep.reports_to=E.Emp_id 
Where E.reports_to=1 or E.emp_id=1;
```

but this is accurate upto 2 level and I cant even generate the hierarchy_level no.
Any suggestion, idea............ will be most helpfull.........

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use a recursive CTE:

```
; with  CTE as 
        (
        select  emp_id
        ,       reports_to
        ,       emp_name
        ,       1 as level
        from    Emp
        where   emp_name = 'Sumanta'
        union all
        select  child.emp_id
        ,       child.reports_to
        ,       child.emp_name
        ,       level + 1
        from    Emp child
        join    CTE parent
        on      child.reports_to = parent.emp_id
        )
select  *
from    CTE
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/60f1e/1/0)

Comment: 'With CTE as (
Select emp_id,emp_Name,reports_to,1 as Level 
From emp Where reports_to=1
Union all
Select E.emp_id,E.emp_name,E.reports_to,Level+1 From emp as E 
Inner join CTE on E.reports_to=CTE.emp_id
)
Select * from CTE;'

Just found exactly what I was looking for.... @Andomar
Thanks

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about SqlFiddle

Comment: @Andomar, tried to follow  "SQL course from Stanford" link from your profile but it seems to be broken. And http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com confirms it

Comment: @ГеннадийВанинНовосибирск: http://online.stanford.edu/db-win13 seems to be the current link :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Common_Table_Expression we can write like this

```
WITH Employee_CTE(employeeid,hierarchy_level,name) AS  
(  
   SELECT employeeid,1 as level,name from employee where employeeid=1 
   UNION ALL  
   SELECT e.employeeid,level +1, e.name 
   from employee e   
   INNER JOIN Employee_CTE c ON e.employeeid = c.managerid  
)  
SELECT * FROM Employee_CTE order by employeeid
```