# SQL Query to get all managers

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL table `worker` with the fields :

```
1. id
2. Name
3. Manager id
```

I was trying to write a query to get a list of following fields ('id','name','manager id', 'manager name')

Note that the manager id also belongs to the **worker** i.e. manager is also a worker. Also, a Manager further has a manager who again belongs to the same table - the hierarchy can rise up to n number of managers (unknown) .

So far this is query I have

`SELECT tab1.user_name, tab1.user_id, tab1.manager_id, tab2.name AS manager_name, 1 AS LEVEL FROM (SELECT tab1.name AS user_name, tab1.id AS user_id, manager_id FROM DB.user tab1 WHERE id = 1 AND active = 1) tab1 LEFT JOIN DB.user tab2 ON tab1.manager_id = tab2.id UNION SELECT tab1.user_name, tab1.user_id, tab1.manager_id, tab2.name AS manager_name, 2 AS LEVEL FROM (SELECT tab1.name AS user_name, tab1.id AS user_id, manager_id FROM DB.user tab1 WHERE manager_id = 1 AND active = 1) tab1 LEFT JOIN DB.user tab2 ON tab1.manager_id = tab2.id UNION SELECT tab1.user_name, tab1.user_id, tab1.manager_id, tab2.name AS manager_name, 
  3 AS LEVEL FROM (SELECT tab1.name AS user_name, tab1.id AS user_id, manager_id FROM DB.user tab1 WHERE manager_id IN (SELECT tab1.id FROM DB.user tab1 WHERE manager_id = 1 AND active = 1) AND active = 1 ) tab1 LEFT JOIN DB.user tab2 ON tab1.manager_id = tab2.id`

But this gets me results upto 3rd level of heirarchy, whereas I need it to be self expanding and to fetch me results to no matter what level the nesting exists.

Can someone please help out.

Comment: what you have tried so far ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232426/get-all-employee-who-directly-or-indirectly-reports-to-an-employee-with-hierarc

Comment: Sounds like homework. Show us what you've tried and exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I misspelled the requirement, what was required was to get all the workers below a manager by the manager id.

Comment: I've added the query in the question

Answer (score 1):

```
select w1.id, w1.name, w2.id as manager_id, w2.name as manager_name
from worker as w1 inner join worker w2 on w1.manager_id = w2.id
```